# iOS - ScrollView Changing Background

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying to change the background on a custom scrollview I've created but for some reason it won't change. Here is the code:

```
@implementation ProfileScrollView
@synthesize changePictureButton;
@synthesize changePictureLabel;
@synthesize nameLabel;
@synthesize genderLabel;
@synthesize ageLabel;
@synthesize writeAboutYourselfLabel;
@synthesize interestsLabel;
@synthesize interestFrame;
@synthesize isDrawn;
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;

    if (self.isDrawn == NO)
    {
        self.changePictureLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:14];
        self.nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:14];
        self.ageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:14];
        self.genderLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:14];
        self.writeAboutYourselfLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:14];
        self.interestsLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:14];

        self.changePictureLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.314 green:0.89 blue:0.761 alpha:1];

        self.interestFrame = self.interestsLabel.frame;

        int startHeight = 0;

        NSMutableArray *interests = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Game of Thrones", @"Starcarft", @"Eating out", @"Soccer", @"Football", @"Video Games", nil];

        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

        int currentWidth = 0;
        for (NSString *interest in interests) {

            CGSize buttonSize = [interest sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:14]}];

            if (currentWidth == 0)
            {
                currentWidth = self.interestFrame.origin.x;
                startHeight = self.interestFrame.origin.y + self.interestFrame.size.height + 5;
            }
            else if (currentWidth > (screenWidth - 30))
            {
                currentWidth = self.interestFrame.origin.x;
                startHeight += (buttonSize.height + 15);
            }

            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(currentWidth, startHeight, buttonSize.width + 15, buttonSize.height + 10);
            CustomButton *aButton = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            [aButton setTitle:interest forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            aButton.buttonColour = [UIColor whiteColor];
            aButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:14];
            aButton.enabled = NO;
            [self addSubview:aButton];
            aButton = nil;

            currentWidth += buttonSize.width + 20;
        }

        CGSize buttonSize = [@"Add +" sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:14]}];

        currentWidth = self.interestFrame.origin.x;
        startHeight += buttonSize.height + 20;

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(currentWidth, startHeight, buttonSize.width + 15, buttonSize.height + 10);
        CustomButton *addButton = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [addButton setTitle:@"Add +" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        addButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:14];
        [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addSubview:addButton];

        self.isDrawn = YES;
    }
}


@implementation MyProfileViewController
@synthesize saveButton;
@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.navController = self.navigationController;
}
```

When I hide the scrollview, the imageview i've set as the background appears correctly but once I put unhide the scrollview the background is black. Any ideas?

Comment: So this doesn't answer your question, but I find it very odd that you're setting fonts and laying things out in -drawRect:. -drawRect: is for actually _drawing_ on the view, not laying out subviews. You might want to put a lot of the font setup in -initWithFrame:, and any dynamic layout in -layoutSubviews. If the user does anything that requires you to recalculate layout, just call [view setNeedsLayout]

Comment: the reason i put it all in -drawRect is this object is created in the xib and if i put all that code in -initWithFrame, it would never get called because if you create an object in a xib, -initWithFrame doesn't get executed.

Comment: In that case use -awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this guys.

I had Opaque set on the xib file.